# Visual Studio Code: Use esnext option?

Tags: ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

I have lots of ES6 related errors in Visual Studio code when working with ES6 JavaScript files. Where can I use the esnext option what the error tells me to do??

[image: "use esnext option" error]

**UPDATE**

Having a `jsconfig.json` with the following is NOT enough:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6"
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use a jsconfig.json file?

Comment: @aloisdg question updated

Answer (score 4):

I've found out: you need a `.jshintrc` file with the following:

```
{
     "esnext": true
}
```

As @aloisdg said: `jsconfig.json` [has an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2942) with this.

Also, `.eslintrc` is not supported at the moment AFAIK.

Comment: Gábor do you know how to set this globally?

Comment: Well, I don't know about a global solution. You might start looking around here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript -- feel free to share if you found anything.

Answer (score 1):

It is a linting issue. You can ignore it.

You may want to check [Salsa](https://code.visualstudio.com/Updates#_javascript-salsa-preview) as recommended in this issue in [the vscode's repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2942).

Also, you may want to add `"module": "commonjs"` in `compilerOptions` into your `jsconfig.json`.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "module": "commonjs"
    }
}
```

Comment: I am glad you find something better to fix your issue.